# Does question on Camera Array and Android Camera consider on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Does questions specifically related to the following consider on-topic?

**Camera Array**

(Reference: http://petapixel.com/2013/01/21/creating-3d-portraits-using-an-array-of-digital-cameras/)

[image]

**Android Camera**

(e.g. Polaroid's Android Camera show in CES 2013)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the question to a certain extent - if it were about writing a program to control the array, then I wouldn't see that as on-topic here, but better suited to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). If the question were about combining the shots to form a video, then that may be better on [Audio-Video production](https://video.stackexchange.com/). For questions about lighting/rigging the array, then that would seem more obviously on-topic; Similarly, if you were asking how to set some obscure setting on an Android powered camera, I would be surprised if people considered it off topic.

Comment: It would be better suited to [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/) if it concerns controlling the camera via Android API. Stack Overflow does cover Android, but really I think they are more general questions than anything else.